# Make X11 react on "dev/input/eventx"?

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, input

I have a debian 7 on kernel 3.8 running with a touchscreen. With evtest, I see that I get the screen's coordinates for device "dev/input/event2". How do I have to configurate my X server, that the cursor is moved with the touched screen?
At the moment, when I touch the screen, the cursor jumps to the left upper edge,

Comment: Nobody? It's really urgent :-(